# Overrided 404 error page, but it's not being displayed

Tags: symfony

I've placed a new 404 template file in:

```
app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig
```

But it's not being shown when 404 is thrown. I've cleared the cache so not sure what else I could do. Any ideas?

Edit: Never mind, apparently it needs to be:

```
app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/exception_full.html.twig
```

Comment: `exception_full.html.twig` is used for dev environment only. In prod `error404.html.twig` would work.

Comment: @MoleculeMan it works now, but not in prod and I've cleared cache. Anything else I should do?